# Defining End of Term (subscription model), from 2 dates, with PHP

Tags: php, date

I am building a script to work with Zapier WebHooks. Zapier will send this script a post request, after gmail receives an email with specifics subjects and messages from the payment gateway.

Anyway, one of the hooks is a message with the subject "Subscription cancelled". I cannot set my script to end the subscription right after receiving this post request, cause I need to keep client access until he reaches the end of his last paid period (I have 3 plans: 1 month, 6 months and 1 year of subscription, with automatical renewal).

The email sent by the gateway comes with data that allows me to know when the subscription was first purchased, in this format: dd/mm/yyyy.

(Easy on me, I am getting there...)

So I have the purchase date and the cancellation date (which is the day my script received the post request). Now comes my doubt: How can I set my script to define the EOT (end of term) based on these 2 dates?

For example, say that a customer have purchased his month membership on 03/02/2015 (dd/mm/yyyy). Then my script is informed about his cancellation on 29/03/2015. I can store these 2 dates in 2 variables: `$purchaseDate` and `$cancellationDate`. Now I need to set my PHP code so it can calculate the EOT (`$eotDate`), which would be, in that case, 03/04/2015.

Being more specific:

1) In case of a month subscription, the `$eotDate` will be the next `$purchaseDate` day (day 03, in the example above) after the `$cancellationDate`.

2) In case of a 6 months subscription, the `$eotDate` will be the `$purchaseDate` day (day 03, in the example above) after 6 months from the `$purchaseDate`, as long as it results in a date in the future. If the result date is (was) in the past, we can assume that there was a renewal, so the `$eotDate` will be the `$purchaseDate` day (day 03) after 12 months from the `$purchaseDate`. And so on.

3) In case of a 1 year subscription, the `$eotDate` will be the `$purchaseDate` day (day 03, in the example above) after 12 months from the `$purchaseDate`, as long as it results in a date in the future. If the result date is (was) in the past, we can assume that there was a renewal, so the `$eotDate` will be the `$purchaseDate` day (day 03) after 24 months from the `$purchaseDate`. And so on.

I am still learning PHP, so I can only define today's date and 1 year (or some days or months from today). But first I need to stablish the cancellation day. I don't know how to, cause the `date()` function will give me the current date (which will change constantly).

```
 $cancellationDate = date("j/m/Y");// Today, 29/03/2015. This cannot be changed.
 $purchaseDate = "03/02/2015"; //example
```

As you can see, I am lost.

To anybody that would like to help but think the task is too much, if you could help only with number 1 (month subscription), I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [DateTime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) in PHP

```
$now=new DateTime("now");
$cancelation_date=new DateTime("2016-04-03"); // A year from now
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think that won't do it.

Comment: It provides a way to do things like `$now->add('+60 days')` or alternatively use the DateInterval class along with it [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)